# Libreoffice suddenly missing on Fedora

Tags: fedora, libreoffice

On my Fedora 20, Libreoffice is suddenly missing. I did not make any changes to the system but it is still missing. It was running fine till yesterday. Its missing from my right click open with menu as well. I re installed it but still can't find it anywhere on the system. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a filesystem corruption, it happened to me a while ago. This is what I did:

1. Removed any leftover packages: `yum remove libreoffice* -y`
2. Cleaned the yum cache: `yum clean all`
3. Force a filesystem check upon next boot: `touch /forcefsck` or `shutdown -rF now`
4. Reinstall your libreoffice suite: `yum install libreoffice-writer libreoffice-calc ...`

It worked for me and it hasn't gone missing ever since. Look out for your drive's health, you can run a S.M.A.R.T. check with the `gnome-disks` utility to see if it is failing.